# JQuery Mobile causing Firebug and Chrome debuggers to fail to stop at breakpoints

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, jquery-mobile, firebug

I ran into an odd issue where I couldn't get either the Chrome or Firebug debuggers to stop at breakpoints I was setting.  The page ran fine, it was writing to the console, just none of my breakpoints would stop the page.

It turned out that if I removed the jQuery Mobile include file:

```
<script src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

then the debugger worked as expected (I'm using JQM for mobile styling, so if I remove the include file my styles just don't work - no JS errors or anything).

I see no errors in the console related to JQM so I'm not sure why that file is causing problems with the debugger.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that my html page does not have a div with "data-role=page" in it (those are created by JS in my app).  I added an empty div with that attribute and the debugger started working again.  I can't take credit for the fix, it belongs to [Kin Blas](https://github.com/jblas).

See full details here:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4206#issuecomment-5448298

This might happen for anyone using templates through Underscore or Mustache and loading them as separate files with Javascript.  I am using Backbone and Underscore.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery Mobile is loading the page dynamically using ajax call and so the JS files are not loaded the standard way. If you don't prevent ajax call using the `rel="external"`, `data-ajax="false"` or `"target"` attribute (reference [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html)), you have to stop your javascript code using `debugger;` statement, that is programmatical breakpoint for Firebug, Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar and of course Chrome Developer Tools.